# How to display horizontal scrollbar when browser screen decreases

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, browser, scrollbar

This is what I made dashboard. Which contains 4 `DIVs`.
when browser is fully open
[image: when browser screen is fully opened]
when I reduce browser's screen size 
[image: When I decreases browser screen.]

I want whenever browser screen decreases ... dashboard `DIVs` should get `horizontal scroll bar` rather than cutting display.
This is my code for how I render partial view in main view.

```
<fieldset>
    <%using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace}))/*, UpdateTargetId = "RecentDiv" }))*/
      { %>


    <div id="MainDashboardDiv">
        <div class="LiveTile">
            <div id="RecentDiv"> 
                    <h4 class="RequestTitle">
                    <%: Html.ActionLink("Recent Requests", "CRMRequestsList", new { requestType = "Recent" })%>
                    </h4>
                <%Html.RenderAction("RecentRequests",Model); %>
            </div>
            <!--End of RecentDiv -->

            <div id="PriorityDiv">
                <h4 class="RequestTitle">
                    <%: Html.ActionLink("High Priority Requests", "CRMRequestsList", new { requestType = "Priority" })%>
                 </h4>

                <%Html.RenderAction("PriorityRequests", Model); %>
            </div>
            <!--End of PriorityDiv -->
        </div>
        <!--End of UpperLiveTiles -->
        <div class="LiveTile">

             <div id="PendingDiv">
                <h4 class="RequestTitle">
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Pending Requests", "CRMRequestsList", new { requestType = "Pending" })%>
                </h4>
                <%Html.RenderAction("PendingRequests", Model); %>

            </div>
            <!--End of PendingDiv -->
            <div id="ApprovedDiv">
                    <h4 class="RequestTitle">
                    <%: Html.ActionLink("Approved Requests", "CRMRequestsList", new { requestType = "Approved" })%>
                    </h4>
                <%Html.RenderAction("ApprovedRequests", Model); %>

             </div>
            <!--End of ApprovedDiv -->


        </div>
        <!--End of LowerLiveTiles -->
    </div>
    <!--End of MainDashboardDiv -->
    <%} %>
    </fieldset>
```

This is CSS which I apply :

```
#MainDashboardDiv {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;  
    padding-bottom: 4%; 
    overflow: hidden;

}
.LiveTile{
    height: 260px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 1%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#RecentDiv, #PendingDiv
{
    width: 48%; 
    display: inline-block; 
    position: relative; 
    height:inherit;
    overflow: scroll;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background:rgba(0,117,149,0.9);
}
#PriorityDiv,#ApprovedDiv
{

    width: 48%;  
    position: relative; 
    height:inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: scroll;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background:rgba(0,117,149,0.9);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This style is the culprit.

```
.LiveTile{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You're telling it to hide anything that doesn't fit within the bounds. Try `scroll` or `auto`.

```
.LiveTile{
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Or

```
.LiveTile{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry I think I got your markup mixed up, you want to target the div under the heading. Try wrapping `Html.RenderAction("RecentRequests",Model);`, `Html.RenderAction("PriorityRequests",Model);`, etc. in a div and apply it to that.

**HTML**

```
<div id="RecentDiv"> 
        <h4 class="RequestTitle">
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Recent Requests", "CRMRequestsList", new { requestType = "Recent" })%>
    </h4>
    <div class="InnerDiv">
        <%Html.RenderAction("RecentRequests",Model); %>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.InnerDiv {
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: Ohk I changed hidden to auto/scroll. But I do not get expected Result. :( @DanielImms

Comment: Try adding `.InnerDiv {width:100%}` maybe, we need the width to be constrainted within the parent box in order for the scrollbars to work. Also remove `overflow:scroll` from `.LiveTile` if it's still there.

Comment: Ok I gave width:100% and ya there is no overflow:scroll written in .LiveTile. @DanielImms I am using div tag in partial view too. In which table is render. So there is div tag in main view as well as partial view.

Comment: So does it make any difference?